# Postgresql role access commutativity

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to figure out exactly how (modern) Postgresql roles relate to each other.

I have two users, main and foo. I want them to behave exactly the same, with foo having access to anything created by main, and vice versa. foo is a member of main.

However, main does not currently have access to tables created by foo. For example, if foo creates a table 'testfoo', any user other than foo in the database, including main, cannot access it. (If main creates a table, all users in main, including foo, do have access.)

Is there any way to update foo or main so that by default access is granted to everyone in the main role? This currently causes problems when someone runs migrations logged in as a personal user (e.g., foo), as any other users don't have access.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Granting main to foo doesn't grant foo to main.  Grants are one way.

If you want all tables created by foo to be accessible to anyone in main you could try:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE foo IN SCHEMA public
GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO main;
```

But you would have to do that for each member of the role `main` and that still doesn't change ownership from the personal user to the group.

I think an event trigger that fires on create statements and changes ownership of the table from the creating role to the main role could work.

Here is some code that may work for you.  I haven't tested it.

```
BEGIN;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION change_ownership()
RETURNS event_trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql

AS $$

DECLARE
    obj record;

    BEGIN

    /* There might be multiple DDL commands.  Check each one to see if it
    creates a table and change the permisions and ownership of the table to
    the main role. */

    FOR obj IN SELECT * FROM pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands()
    LOOP

    IF obj.object_type = 'table'
       AND tg_tag IN ('CREATE TABLE',
                      'CREATE TABLE AS')
    THEN

        RAISE NOTICE 'Table % created with % statement.',
                     obj.object_identity,
                     tg_tag;

        EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE %I.%I OWNER TO main;',
                       obj.SCHEMA_NAME,
                       SUBSTRING(obj.object_identity FROM '[^.]*$'));

    END IF;
    END LOOP;
END $$;

CREATE EVENT TRIGGER table_creation_trigger
ON ddl_command_end
EXECUTE PROCEDURE change_ownership();

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Thanks - assuming that I don't just want it for tables (e.g., sequences, views), would it be problematic to just remove the IF condition and call 'REASSIGN OWNED BY'? Or do you see that creating other problems?

Comment: @terry87 I don't know exactly.  The code runs at the end of every DDL statement.   I don't think there would be issues caused by other types of statements but I haven't tested it with that.  This is based loosely off of some other code I have used but it only focuses on tables.  So, I think so but have never tried that.